# After installing app as npm package, “vue-cli-service” not found

Tags: npm, webpack, vuejs3

I have a package that is a vuejs application. If I install it local to my project with "npm i 'path/to/app-vuejs --save-dev'" and then run

```
npm explore app-vuejs -- npm run serve
```

everything works. Server gets startet and I can view the generated pages. But after publishing on npm, installing it with 'npm i app-vuejs --save-dev' and run the command again I get the error

```
sh: vue-cli-service: command not found
```

I have now seen that the node-modules directory is different than in my local version... I tried to find the vue-cli-service and saw that I have many more folders in my local version than in my  installed by npm

**local installation:**
[image: local folder structure]

**installation from npm with less dependencies and no vue-cli:**
[image: install from npm]

What need I to do that all node-modules including "cli-services" get installed?

this is my folder structure

```
- main-project
  - node_modules
    - helper-app-vuejs
```

Comment: What are the contents of `package.json` for `helper-app-vuejs`? What is its package name in the public `npm` repo (if that's where you published it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Move the `@vue/cli-service` at `package.json` from the `devDependencies` section to `dependencies`

The `vue-cli-service` is by default a devDependency and will not be part of the published version on npm, because devDependencies are only needed for development *of this package*. If you install your npm-package with `npm i xxxx -save-dev`, only the `dependencies` will be installed, because by definition these dependencies are needed at runtime. If you move the  `@vue/cli-service` package to the `dependencies` section at `package.json` it will be ready at runtime of your other package.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's just something that went wrong with `node_modules` when installing, have you tried: `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`?

If it doesn't work have a look at this:
[vue-cli-service: command not found](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2404)

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly normal by my side. When you run :
`npm install` on local enviroment you are gonna install both devDependencies and prodDependencies (Dependencies).
When you install from npm public artifactory you are gonna use `npm install --prod`

When you publish an artifact you only allow to enduser to install prodDependencies, so not your devDependencies (missing vue-cli-service). Hope can be usefull